# How to check if both username and email are already registered?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have tried various ways but can't seem to solve this. The latest approach I have tried was creating two "findOne" functions, but it still fails.

```
         const checkUser = registerLogin.findOne({ username }, (err, user) => {
          return user;
         });

         registerLogin.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            else if (checkUser)
                res.status(403).json({ registerErrRequired: "Username is taken." });    

            else if (user)
                    res.status(403).json({ registerErrRequired: "Email is already in use." });

            else if (!REGEX.test(email))
                res.status(403).json({ registerErrRequired: "Invalid email." });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator to do it. Something like:

```
registerLogin.findOne({$or: [{email: email}, {username: username}]}, (err, user) => {...})
```

Comment: It works well, and I know this is not part of the main question, but I am a bit stuck on distinguishing the errors. Since both share the same user, both have the same error messages. I tried something like user.username, which does not work.

Comment: you can check if user.username == username or user.email == email to send the error

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code snippet below:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

// Validate the user data
const { value, error } = validations.registerValidation(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

// Checking if the user is already in database
const emailExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (emailExist) return res.status(400).send({ Message: 'Email already exists!' });

// Hash password
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

// Create a new user
const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword
});
try {
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.send({ user: savedUser._id });
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
}
```

});

Comment: Your answer only responds to only one registered document of email, not two documents of email and username.